# Freezing Ubuntu while installing from live usb

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation, usb

I have tried to do a live usb from different resources ultraiso, universal usb, rufus, but always have the same effect, the setup freezes after some minutes. I even tried doing live dvd, but it had even worser effect, there was an error something about "unhandled reference in kernel" and some stack trace with whole bunch of addresses.

So maybe you can advise me some setup magic, so I don't have this kind of error.
Because I didn't find the right solution for this googling through forums, questions etc.

My PC:

- processor: intel-i7 4700
- videocard: nvidia gtx 770m
- ram: 16gb

And I guess it's important to know I have windows 10 alongside installing ubuntu, my secure boot is disabled.

Tell me if you need more info and thanks for answering.

Comment: Did you [verify the integrity](//help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of the disk image(s) used as source to create the installation media? Next thing to try would be the [official instructions to create a Live USB/DVD medium](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/) (choose the right method for your operating system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to boot with `nomodeset` parameter, then install Ubuntu, then boot with `nomodeset` the installed system.

[This is the guide how to boot with nomodeset](https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/167850).

Then you will need to install video drivers

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```